Working principle of transimpedance amplifier
I have basic questions about the following configuration of an Op-Amp, which is transimpedance amplifier, I would appreciate your help to help me understand this:

First question, considering that the positive input of the Op-Amp is connected to GND, then Op-Amp will try to keep the negative input voltage also to zero(GND), then there is no voltage different in the inputs of the Ap-Amp, so I assume the output voltage should be zero finally,considering the gain will be multiplied by zero but why it is not zero?
I will do my best to answer based on my current knowledge and make an active effort. Please feel free to correct me if I am mistaken.
Considering there is current flow through R1, then there is a voltage across this resistor, so the output voltage will adjust itself in a way that the negative input pin is still zero, so how much this argument is correct? but still how can I justify the previous argument that I made? when there is no potential difference between positive and negative, then the output should be zero?! to be this too contradicts, unless I am missing a critical point here.

If there is current at input, then it will "reflect" to output through R1-C1 ...

So, if we consider the reason of output voltage is that the current path through C1 and R1, then what is the purpose of having the Op-Amp?

If the current is very "low" (some pA & nA), then voltage will be "high" at output through R1 (very high value resistor, some GOhm).

@Andromeda - Hi, You're asking about that schematic, so is it yours? Or was it copied / adapted from elsewhere? In that case, to comply with the site referencing rule, please include a reference to its original source. TY

@SamGibson thanks for for your comment, it is my own simulation.

@Andromeda, However, let me ask you, do you understand what the op-amp actually does and why it does it here?

@Circuit fantasist not exactly, it is not very clear for me, what is the op-amp role here?

@Andromeda, Perhaps I should write an answer illustrated with schematics, but in short: the op-amp adds as much voltage to the circuit as is lost across the resistor R1, thus compensating for the voltage drop. As a result, the input current source "sees"  zero resistance (a "piece of wire") and zero voltage (virtual ground). This eliminates the error that would be caused by the resistor R1 if the input source were not a perfect current source.

@Circuit fantasist vow, it was a great explanation, thanks a lot , I would appreciate if you can also illustrate it in a schematic when ever you had time, thanks you very much again.

@ Andromeda - in order to illustrate the statements made by circuit fantasist, you should realize that in your drawing the elements R2 and C4 are modelling a non-ideal current source. And it is the advantage of the shown circuit that these two elements do NOT appear in the transfer ratio which is simply Vout/I=-Z1=-R1||(1/sC1)

@Andromeda, I apologize profusely... Yesterday, I crafted a comprehensive answer for you, complete with ten CircuitLab schematics illustrating the step-by-step reinvention of the circuit. Unfortunately, I inadvertently overwrote it and its backup with another answer. I'm uncertain if I'll be able to reproduce it in its entirety...

@Circuit fantasist thank you very much for your help, still I appreciate that you made the effort, thanks a lot.

@Andromeda, And miracles do happen in this world :-) I managed to recover the schematics and now I'm writing the explanations for them.

@Circuit fantasist great news

@Andromeda, I've constructed a narrative centered around the legendary circuit. It's designed to convey a broader concept rather than specific details. To enhance its clarity, I would welcome any questions you may have regarding any aspect that seems ambiguous.

Introduction
To unveil the core concept behind this iconic circuit, I will delve into the simpler case of a "transresistance amplifier". I favor using more descriptive terms like "current-to-voltage converter" or even "ammeter", as this is essentially how a modern "ideal" ammeter functions (I-to-V and ADC).
Resistance represents the ratio of voltage to current when both quantities are applied at the same point. Here, it signifies a voltage drop (loss).
Transresistance comes into play when these quantities are spatially separated – current at the input, voltage at the output. In this context, we are dealing with a voltage gain (power gain); hence, the circuit exhibits negative resistance characteristics.
The best way to learn is by doing. So let's build this circuit step by step and see how it works.
Perfect ammeter
First, imagine that we have an "ideal" ammeter with zero internal resistance...
Perfect current source
... and we want to measure the current output of an "ideal" current source. Both source and ammeter are perfect so there is absolutely no issue in measuring the current. As the ammeter's resistance is zero, there is no voltage drop VA across it. Consequently, the current source faces no opposition in delivering its specified 1 mA current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Imperfect current source (1)
Even if the current source was not perfect, the ammeter would still accurately measure the current. For instance, if a 1 kΩ resistor Rin were connected in parallel (as in your schematic), it would have no impact on the measurement because it would be effectively shorted out by the "ideal"  ammeter (no current flows through Rin).

simulate this circuit
Imperfect current source (2)
The same would be true if we had constructed a simple current source by connecting a 1 kΩ resistor Rin in series with a 1 V voltage source Vin.

simulate this circuit
Imperfect ammeter
Let's now examine the same three cases but with an imperfect ammeter having some (e.g. RA = 1 kΩ) internal resistance. We can also used the voltage drop across it as a voltage output Vout.
Perfect current source
It would typically reduce the measured current. However, in our "ideal" current source configuration, the voltage increases by 1 V, which compensates for this reduction, effectively maintaining the current.

simulate this circuit
Imperfect current source (1)
However, if the current source is imperfect, for example, with a parallel-connected resistor Rin, the current decreases because part of it diverts through Rin.

simulate this circuit
Imperfect current source (2)
The current will also decrease if we have created an imperfect current source using a voltage source Vin and a resistor Rin in series because the total resistance Rin + RA has increased.

simulate this circuit
Improved ammeter
So we need to improve the imperfect ammeter.
Basic idea
It is more than obvious: since voltage is lost across the resistance, we must add the same voltage to the circuit.
Conceptual circuit
Man-controlled voltage source: This means that we must connect an additional voltage source VA in series and make its voltage equal to the voltage drop across the resistor.

simulate this circuit
Behavioral voltage source: We can assign this routine to a behavioral VCVS...

simulate this circuit
Negative resistor: ... or even to a negative resistor -RA with the same but negative resistance of -1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
Op-amp circuit
In real electronic circuits, this task is typically performed by an op-amp.

simulate this circuit

simulate this circuit
Conclusions

In the circuit of a transimpedance amplifier, the op-amp adds as much voltage to the circuit as is lost across the feedback resistor R. As a result,

the voltage drop is compensated,

the input current source "sees" zero resistance (a "piece of wire") and zero voltage (virtual ground).

This eliminates the error that would be caused by the resistor Rin (in parallel or in series) if the input source was not a perfect current source.

The compensating voltage can be used as a negative voltage output.



thank you very much for the great explanation, I really enjoyed and learned a lot.

Quote: ".... then there is no voltage different in the inputs of the Ap-Amp, so I assume the output voltage should be zero"
No - that is not correct. The feedback effect makes the input differential voltage (between inverting and non-inv. inputs) NEARLY zero - in reality some µVolts.
However - during calculations, it is common practice to assume that this voltage is zero because , normally, it can be neglected against all other voltages within the circuit (due to the opamps excessive open-loop gain Aol).
For calculation of the circuits gain we can use the superposition theorem:
1) Vout=0: Vn1=-I*(Z1||Z2) with Z1=R1||Xc1 and Z2=R2||Xc4
2) Source I removed: Vn2=Vout*Z2/(Z2+Z1)
3) Setting Vn=Vn1+Vn2=0 the transfer ratio Vout/I can be calculated.
(As you can see, we set Vn=0. If you want, you can set Vn=Vout/Aol with Aol=1E5...1E4 and evaluate the difference to the simplified result).

EDIT (alternative calculation):
An even simpler approach for finding the transfer ratio for the given circuit is based on the current distribution.

The current through Z2 will be zero because there is no potential difference across Z2 (ideal opamp with Vn=0).

Therefore, the current through Z1 (from left to right) ist identical to the source current I.

However, at the same time the current through Z1 can also be expressed as I=-Vout/Z1.

Hence, we have Vout/I=-Z1


